# Python: IDE или редактор кода?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pycharm, atom

Только начинаю изучать Python, встал вопрос об организации рабочего процесса. У меня уже есть небольшой опыт создания HTML страниц, а Python учится в основном для написания небольших приложений на Django "для себя".

HTML-код пишу в редакторе vscode. В нем есть поддержка Python, но она "доставляется" плагином. Практически во всех статьях пишут, что лучше PyCharm сложно что то найти.

https://programfiles.info/python/luchshie-besplatnye-ide-i-redaktory-koda-dlya-python/

Но у меня не очень мощный ноутбук, и он работает значительно медленнее того же vscode или atom.

Вопрос наверно больше к тем, кто в свое время перешел на эту IDE с редактора: реально ли он упрощает жизнь разработчику? Стоит ли покупать платную версию (в бесплатной нет подсказок по Django)?

Comment: Лично я использую PyCharm только для работы с Django. Pro версия действительно сильно упрощает жизнь. Если занимаетесь Web-разработкой, IMHO, стоит покупать. Но IDE (любая) очень долго загружается. Для написания скриптов и быстрофиксов у меня Sublime.

Comment: @Dasnet Я достаточно давно использую Pycharm, да и другие продукты jetbrains. После настройки pycharm "под себя" на 100% могу сказать, что он значительно упрощает работу, не только веб, но и ии.

Comment: Пользуйтесь тем, что вам нравится и то, что поддерживает ваш компьютер без тормозов. PyCharm хорош в своих аспектах, VS Code в своих. Использование только одного или другого инструмента не сделает вас профессиональней, вы не научитесь быстрей и ничего не потеряете, если будете использовать VS Code вместо PyCharm или наоборот.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал вообще Jupyter Notebooks изучить. Для каких-то целей такой формат гораздо удобнее. Кроме того, можно использовать Google Colaboratory и делать всё там, тогда мощность вашего ноутбука не играет никакой роли. Но зависит от ваших задач. Для исследовательских целей Colaboratory просто шикарный инструмент.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно использовать IDE на этапе обучения. Во-первых, IDE избавляет вас от рутинных операций, но именно рутинные операции позволяют набить руку . Во-вторых, IDE скрывает многие процессы, выполняя их за программиста, но именно они позволяют понять базовые принципы. Так что IDE надо начинать использовать только тогда, когда ты уже профи, всё знаешь и тебе надо увеличить производительность труда.

Answer (score 1):

Многие не знают о прекрасной бесплатной IDE [Eric](https://eric-ide.python-projects.org/), хотя он всегда входил в тройку лучших. И знаете почему? Потому что во время ее инсталляции тебе нужно так много знать о том, что и зачем тебе нужно включить из огромного количества ее инструментов. Да и сама инсталляция не детская. Вот попробуйте исследовать его.
Мое мнение такое: Python язык "для взрослых". Не забываем, что дух сообщества Python  это свободное создание свободных инструментов. Поэтому лично мне платные оболочки кажутся "не в духе" сообщества.
Итого

1. Если вам нужны подсказки, то их на хорошем компьютере дает и
   бесплатный Spyder 4.0 поставляемый с Anaconda. Он попроще чем
   бесплатный же Eric.
2. Я бы порекомендовал вам остаться на VS Code, а подсказки брать из
   документации Django.
3. Самым правильым (и я поддерживаю предыдущего советчика) я бы начал
   изучение WEB-фреймворков с Flask, причем для написания кода
   использовал бы Notebook++

Вот сравнение возможностей [Eric vs PyCharm](https://www.slant.co/versus/1240/1244/~pycharm-professional-edition_vs_eric-python-ide).  Вот какие никакие уроки по [установке Eric](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEnWfUUksJ0&list=PLuZJ9n46uMzUFVX_1F87vfsyhq4CLu-gY&index=2&t=0s).   Вот сравнение возможностей разных [IDE for Python](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/compare-python-code-editors-ide).
Ну и  в заключение мнение django-разработчика о 12-ти разных [IDE](https://djangostars.com/blog/python-ide/), PyCharm и Eric в том числе.
Выбирай сам. Платить за удобство "автоматической коробки передач" PyCharm или своими руками собрать "авто с ручным переключением скоростей" Eric. В этой аналогии VS Code  - это авто с конвейера с ручной коробкой. ;-)

Comment: Можно не платить за PyCharm: использовать бесплатную Community версию или [EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/). Также есть возможность бесплатного использования Pro версии, например, для студентов: [Special offers](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/buy/#discounts). По поводу Eric - тут как бы выбор не между ручной и автоматической коробкой передач или платностью и бесплатностью, а между "сел, завел и поехал" (PyCharm, Vscode, Spyder) и некоторыми плясками с бубном прежде чем вообще заведется (Eric).

Comment: ну я ж так и написал:  или своими руками собрать "авто с ручным переключением скоростей" Eric.
благодаря вашему замечанию  вычленил  VS Code - в отдельную группу - магазинное авто с ручной коробкой )