# Ошибка при работе на JAVA в NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Делаю первые шаги в освоении программирования и меня немного пугает красная строчка warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
1 warning в консоли
При этом программа выполняется,пожалуйста объясните как это устранить и стоит ли

Comment: мой совет: перейди на intelij idea, тебе для обучения community edition вполне подойдет, а если позже тебя потянет на джуна, тебе как студенту бесплатно предоставят ultimate;

Comment: Мой совет: [не используйте IDE на этапе обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1080558/204271).

Comment: Дело в том,что я обучаюсь через курс от академии оракл и там использование NetBeans это обязательное условие